# Poisson processes and ballistic missiles

Tags: probability, statistics

> In response to an attack of 10 missiles, a response of 500 antiballistic missiles are launched. The missile targets of each antimissile are independent, and equiprobably picked. Each antimissile has a $.1$ chance to hit. What is the probability of all 10 missiles being hit?

The question then asks the student to use a Poisson process, although I'm willing to solve this using other methods. I thought I'd have

$$X=\sum X_i$$

with

$$X_i=1,0$$

if hit or not hit respectively. Then

$$P(X_i=1)=\sum_{k=1}^{500}\,_{500}\text{C}_kp^k(1-p)^{500-k}$$

and $p=1/100$.

I'm fairly certain my approach is wrong, and I do not know how to finish the problem.

Comment: I have seen this question before on this site. I don't have the link at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Exact Answer**

For the exact answer, I would approach this using Inclusion-Exclusion.

Let $N_j$ be the event that incoming missile $j$ is missed.

The intersection of $k$ of the $N_j$ is $k$ particular missiles being missed. There is a $\frac{k}{10}$ chance that any will be targeted by a given anti-missile and a $\frac1{10}$ chance that that anti-missile will hit. Thus, there is a $\left(1-\frac{k}{10}\cdot\frac1{10}\right)$ chance that that anti-missile will miss, and a $\left(1-\frac{k}{100}\right)^{500}$ chance that all $500$ will miss. There are $\binom{10}{k}$ ways to choose the $k$ particular missiles Thus, the sum of the probabilities of $k$ missiles being missed by $500$ anti-missiles is
$$
\binom{10}{k}\left(1-\frac{k}{100}\right)^{500}
$$
Inclusion-Exclusion says that the probability of some missile not being hit is
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{10}(-1)^{k-1}\binom{10}{k}\left(1-\frac{k}{100}\right)^{500}=0.0638876
$$
Thus, the probability of all $10$ missiles being hit is $0.9361124$

---

**Poisson Approximation**

Since there are $500$ anti-missiles, each with a probability of $\frac1{100}$ of targeting a particular incoming missile, the expected number of hits on each missile is $5$. Thus, the Poisson approximation for getting no hits on a particular incoming missile is $e^{-5}$. Therefore, the probability of getting at least one hit on each particular missile is $\left(1-e^{-5}\right)$ and the probability of hitting all $10$ is
$$
\left(1-e^{-5}\right)^{10}=0.9346272
$$
This is pretty close to the exact answer.

Comment: These answers makes sense to me. I appreciate the thoroughness. Thanks!

Comment: @robjohn Could one also say that the probability a particular missile is hit is $(1-(1-0.01)^{500})^{10}=0.9362042...$? Or is this wrong? It seems to be really close to the answer, is this just a fluke?

Comment: @GuachoPerez I think that works too. The raising to the 10th power is not exact because the events of "at least one anti-missile hits missile j" and "at least one anti-missile hits missile k" are not technically independent, but they are very close to independent, and when we use Poisson we assume that too.

Comment: Can you explain how you got the probability $1/100$ in Poisson approximation?

Comment: There is a $\frac1{10}$ chance that a given ABM will target a particular missile and a $\frac1{10}$ chance that it will hit that missile. That gives a $\frac1{100}$ chance that a given ABM will hit a particular missile.

Comment: @robjohn 
I don't understand how this poisson approach works. Suppose I change the question as follows - There is only $1$ missile, $1$ antiballistic missile and probability of hitting is $1$. So, probability that all missiles are being hit should also be $1$. Now, by your approach, the expected number of hits on each missile should be $1$. So the probability of getting at least one hit on each particular missile is $(1-e^{-1})$. So, the probability I will get will be $(1-e^{-1})^{1}=0.632$ which is not $1$.

Comment: Does $(1+1)^1=e$? No, but $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n=e$. The Poisson approximation is just that, an approximation. [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3855277) shows that as the numbers of events gets larger, the Poisson approximation gets closer to the actual probability for much the same reason. Even with $500$ ABMs, the probability does not match exactly.

Answer (score 1):

This is problem 4.68 in "A first course in probability, 9th edition" by Ross. The back of the book claims that the answer is $\exp(-10e^{-5})  \approx 0.93484$. Let's reverse engineer that:

First, consider the 10 missiles and examine one of them, let's call it $M$. Let $X$ be the random variable that gives the number of anti-missiles that will hit $M$. Since each anti-missile has a $0.1 \times \frac{1}{10} = 0.01$ chance of hitting $M$, we see that $X$ is approximately Poisson with mean $500 \times 0.01 = 5$. Hence, the probability that no anti-missiles will hit $M$ is $e^{-5}$.

Next, let $Y$ be the random variable that gives the number of missiles that have no anti-missiles hitting them. This is approximately Poisson with mean $10 \times e^{-5}$. Hence the probability that all of the 10 missiles will have at least one anti-missile hitting it is equivalent to the the probability that none of the 10 missiles are unhit. This is just $\exp(-10e^{-5})$, QED.

Comment: I don't understand this result and approach. Suppose I change the question as follows - There is only 1 missile, 1 antiballistic missile and probability of hitting is 1. So, probability that all missiles are being hit should also be 1. Now, by your approach, $X$ will be Poisson with mean $1\times 1\times 1=1$ and so $Y$ will be Poisson with mean $1\times e^{-1}$. So, the probability I will get will be $exp(-e^{-1}) = 0.6922$ which is not $1$.

Comment: it's not surprising that this approach fails when probability is 1, since you are no longer [in the Poisson regime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Assumptions_and_validity). In particular, the assumption that your case breaks is that you are constraining $k=1$. In contrast, the problem has 10 missiles, so you can have $k = 0$, $k=1$, $k=2$, etc. Of course, you cannot have $k > 10$, but that's okay because 10 is high enough for the approximation to be close.